# Whole Screen GridView with Six Element Android

Tags: android

I want to make a grid View like below in android
**Grid View with Six element**  and Covering whole the Screen 
and **Supporting Multiple Screen Sizes** 
I have Tried  the Different Solution but unable to achieve the Desire Result 
Kindly if you have any

> Tip or Trick

Share with 
How I can Achieve This?

[image]

My GridView

```
<GridView
    android:id="@+id/menugrid"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_above="@+id/levelselection_back"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:listSelector="#0fff"
    android:numColumns="3"
    android:stretchMode="columnWidth"
    android:verticalSpacing="15dp" >
</GridView>
```

Comment: What you have tried show us.

Comment: Isn't your problem get solved yet???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have fixed number of elements to display then **TableLayout** or **LinearLayout** with *weightsum* would be better option rather than **GridView**

Answer (score 1):

Try following code. This code will provide `Multiple Screen` support with equal sized buttons. You can remove `Buttons` and put any other view you want.

**Note:**

If you want to provide some space around it, please use Horizontal Spacing and Vertical Spacing. I didn't use in this layout.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TableLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" >

        <TableRow
            android:id="@+id/tableRow5"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1" >

            <Button
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text="1" />

            <Button
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text="2" />

            <Button
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text="3" />
        </TableRow>

        <TableRow
            android:id="@+id/tableRow1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1" >


            <Button
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text="4" />

            <Button
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text="5" />

            <Button
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text="6" />
        </TableRow>
    </TableLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```